# unresponsive bars in otherwise responsive grouped d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, responsive

I am trying to build a **responsive** grouped d3 bar chart using this as a guide:

http://blog.webkid.io/responsive-chart-usability-d3/

I have also used this for guidance on creating the grouped chart:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

I now have a chart that resizes the axis and gridlines on window resize, but the bars (rects) remain fixed.  Based on the code from mbostock's example, it's unclear to me what needs to change to allow the bars to move to their new positions as the x axis resizes.

Code samples below from the 3 key methods.  `init` gets run and calls `render` on first load.  Then the event listener for window resize runs `render`.

code from init method:

```
x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(d => d.label));
x1 = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(scales);
y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5]);

xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient('bottom');
yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient('left')

svg = d3.select(element).append('svg');
chartWrapper = svg.append('g');
chartWrapper.append('g').classed('x axis', true);
chartWrapper.append('g').classed('y axis', true);
```

code from render method:

```
x.rangeBands([0, width]);
x1.rangeRoundBands([0, x.rangeBand()]);
y.range([height, 0]);

svg
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
chartWrapper.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

xAxis.scale(x);
yAxis.scale(y);

svg.select('.x.axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis)

svg.select('.y.axis')
  .call(yAxis)

bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(data)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + x(d.label) + ", 0)");

bars.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d.scores)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(125, 21)")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", d => x1(d.name))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
    .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value))
```

code from updateDimensions:

```
margin.top = 20;
margin.right = 10;
margin.left = 125;
margin.bottom = 110;

width = elementWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

I'll also add that I've looked into some of the other solutions for responsive charts, such as using the viewBox to resize the entire svg.  I prefer the approach of using a window resize event handler so I can make modifications to the chart for smaller devices.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: We're gonna need more code that that to help you.

Comment: ok added the code from each of the three key methods driving the creation of the chart and subsequent re-rendering on window resize.  Hope it's better than what was there before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I have found a solution.  Dunno if it's a good one, but it gets the job done!

adding `svg.selectAll('.bar').remove();` prior to adding the bar elements was the trick.